# Removing the Chinese text "未写入google key和tee key" watermark on the screen

Tags: custom-roms

After flashing a custom ROM, there is a watermark in the top-right of the screen saying

> [image]
>
> 未写入google key和tee key

I've googled it and have tried several of the solutions suggested, but none have worked. Interestingly, most people get a slightly different variation of this message, in red.

I've removed "FactoryTest" from my phone, but do not have `com.mediatek.factorymode` as some have suggested. I've messed around with my IMEI keys, this did not help. The message also still appears even with the SIM card removed.

Where on the phone could this be stored? My phone is rooted, so if I could locate the file responsible, I could easily delete it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [Minimal ADB and Fastboot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790) on the computer
2. Plug in the phone into the computer, but keep the phone on
3. On the computer, open the terminal/command prompt
4. Enter these commands

   ```
   adb devices
   adb shell
   pm list packages
   pm uninstall --user 0 com.mediatek.factorymode
   ```
5. Restart the phone and the watermark will be removed

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work unfortunately. Seems I don't have this package installed on my phone.

Comment: @KaptainKris The watermarks are gone!! For me it worked. You have to leave the cell phone on, not in stand-by mode. In addition, USB debugging and OEM (bootloader) must be allowed in developer mode. Confirm USB debugging again when prompted after connecting the mobile phone to the PC. If you follow this, then the given commands will be accepted. Otherwise errors are displayed. It is actually quite simple.

Comment: it might be `package:com.mediatek.engineermode`, which I didn't risk to uninstall (I don't really know what's that).
I did `pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.watermark` and so watermark is gone.
You might need to lookup for a solution to actually fix it instead of hiding. In this case you need SNWriter, which I couldn't really use.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully removed the watermarks with "tee" and/or "google" words in Ulefone Armor 3WT.

Many sources suggested 2 possible solutions:

1. Kill the service name "sdrpmbFloat" from the Developer options (not work for me)
2. Using ADB, delete the package called `com.mediatek.engineermode` or `com.mediatek.factorymode` or `com.android.watermark` (again, it didn't work for me, I couldn't find the packages)

But, I found another solution.

I had to **comment/delete** the line `ro.agui_tee=TRUSTKERNEL` in the file `/system/product/build.prop` (**need root**) just in case that line does not exist in the file `/system/build.prop`.

So, to root Ulefone with MTKroot app: https://www.ayudaroot.com/root/ulfone/como-hacer-root-en-los-telefonos-moviles-ulefone-armor-3wt/ (Spanish)

And where I found a similar solution: https://www.phonandroid.com/forum/threads/ulefone-armor-9-imei-manquant-et-erreurs-tee-google-resolu.208178/ (French)

Answer (score 0):

You can kill/uninstall the sdrpmbFloat view service with root permissions.
You should be able to go to Developer Options > Active Services to disable the service.

Source: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/ulefone-power-3s-problem.3794521/post-77513923